# Can Allah accept bad duas?

Tags: dua

Can bad duas get accepted? Im confused.Please give me types of bad duas that are accepted and not accepted.The only bad dua that i know is accepted is doing dua against others,but there are other duas that cant be accepted and i dont know what is it.

Comment: Please take the time to write a well thought out question to make it clear what exactly you're looking for in an answer. Just re-posting the same question because you don't like the answers you already got and expecting a different result is a waste of everyone's time.

Answer (score 1):

It is not permissible to pray against somebody because of this hadith

- *Muslim (3014) narrated that the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him)* *said: “Do not pray against yourselves, do not pray against your children, do not pray* a*gainst your wealth, lest that coincide with a time when Allaah is asked and He answers* *your prayer.”*

also, this verse of the Quran strongly relates to the matter

8 **“Not for you (O Muhammad, but for Allaah) is the decision; whether He turns in mercy to** **(pardons) them or punishes them; verily, they are the Zaalimoon (polytheists, disobedients and wrongdoers)”**

**[Aal ‘Imraan 3:128]**

If by praying against someone you meant cursing. That is allowed for specific things but you need to be very careful because of the hadith

- *Abu Ad-Darda reported: The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be upon him,* *said:Verily, when a servant curses something, the curse rises to the heaven and the gates* of* *heaven close upon it. It turns right and left and if it does not find somewhere to go, it* *will return to that which was cursed only if it deserved to be curse, otherwise the curse* *will return to the one who made it.*

*Source: Sunan Abu Dawud 4905, Grade: Hasan*

- *It is permissible to curse all those whom Allaah and His Messenger have cursed, but a*s *for cursing specific people, if it is known that the person died in kufr, then it is* *permissible to curse him. But with regard to a specific [Muslim] evildoer, we should not* *curse him, because the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) forbade* cursing *the person who used to drink wine, even though he had cursed the wine-drinkers in* *general*; *however cursing a specific person if he is an evildoer or promoter of bid’ah *is a point of dispute among the scholars.*

*And Shaykh Ibn ‘Uthaymeen said in al-Qawl al-Mufeed, 1/226.*

Comment: So short answer is no?

Comment: No it’s given a condition